# Error loading Socket.io with RequireJS

Tags: node.js, requirejs, socket.io

I've been trying to load Socket.io into my application using RequireJS but it just keeps giving errors.

Versions used:

- **NodeJS:** 0.10.17
- **Socket.io:** 0.9.16
- **Socket.io-client:** 0.9.16
- **RequireJS:** 2.1.8

### Solutions tried:

- From: https://gist.github.com/guerrerocarlos/3651490

**index.html**

```
require.config({
    shim: {
        'socketio': {
            exports: 'io'
        },
    },
    wrap: false,
    paths: {
        socket: '/socket.io/socket.io',
        jquery: "jquery-2.0.3.min",
        // Other dependencies
    }
});
require(["open_rpg"],function(OpenRPG){
    // App code here
});
```

**file.js**

```
define(["socket"],
    function(io){
        // Socket started here
```

Before using RequireJS socket was working. The Socket JS file is correctly loaded.

**Output:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined
```

---

- From: https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io-client/issues/497

I tried loading Socket.io as a normal JS script, and using:

```
paths:
  "socket.io": 'empty:'
```

But that returns:

```
Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function () { return io; }
```

---

**Update:**
Since NodeJS keeps a modules cache I have added a modified copy of the Socket.io.js file, with line 107 changed as per solution 2 (See the link), and although this works, it's not a real solution. So I will keep this question open.

I have also tried adding the source of SocketIO as a normal JS file, and removing all references to it in RequireJS, but it still seems to be incompatible.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue has been resolved as of version 1.0, so updating to 1.* should work again. Alternatively, the fix you proposed should work as well.

Comment: @andygoestohollywood See https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/blob/master/socket.io.js#L1 (no need for shimming anymore btw)

Answer (score 1):

*/socket.io/socket.io* is delivered by the nodejs's socket.io module and it is meant to be directly used. There is a short snippet which in theory should do the trick, but I'm not sure that it works with RequireJS.

```
if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
  define([], function () { return io; });
}
```

You may download the whole client-side socket.io js and put it in *define(...)* statement.

```
define(function(){

    function add(a, b){
        return a + b;
    }

    return {
        add:add
    };
});
```

Comment: What should I do with the snippet provided? Add the socket.io script as a normal JS script and then add this?

Comment: No, I mean that this snippet is added to socket.io code. What it does is that it checks if there is *define* method defined and register socket.io for amd usage. However, it looks like it doesn't work, so you should get the code and wrap it in define statement. (check my answer again)

Comment: I see what you mean, it might work, but I can't seem to refresh the Node.js modules cache, so the new version of socket.io doesn't update.

Comment: Since I couldn't get the cache to reload, I added another copy of the Socket.io.js file to the public folder, and used the solution of changing line 107. I still don't consider that as a real solution, so I will only update my question to reflect that I've done that, while waiting for someone to come up with a solution that doesn't involve modifying the source. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is right but you need to do one thing that you have to start socket server before loading **index.html** file

I have tried below code and it working fine for me.

**index.html**

> require.config({
>
> ```
> paths: {
>     "socket.io": '/socket.io/socket.io',
>     "jquery": "jquery-2.0.3.min"
> } });
> ```

**file.js**

> define(["socket.io"],
>       function(io)
>   {
>
> ```
>     // Socket started here
> ```

hope this will work for you

Comment: With what version of Socket.io did you test this? It might have been fixed by now

Comment: @Chevi... I have used  0.9.16 version of socket.io. same version that you used. but i haven't write a shim configuration in my code.

Answer (score 0):

My solution like below:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: "/",
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'path/to/jquery.min',
        'socketio': 'path/to/socket.io'
    },
    shim: {
        'jquery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'socketio': {
            exports: 'io'
        }
}
});
require(['jquery', 'socketio'], function($, io){
    // your code
})
```

I hope it can help you!